# How to avoid duplicate event listener in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in react with many input components. I do not like that I have to write a new onChange handler method for every input component that I build. So I want to know how can I stop repeated code.

```
            <Input
              label={"Blog Name"}
              hint={"e.g. 'The Blog'"}
              type={"text"}
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this, "name")}
            />

            <Input
              label={"Blog Description"}
              hint={"e.g. 'The Blog Description'"}
              type={"text"}
              value={this.state.desc}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this, "desc")}
            />
```

So instead of writing a new function I am reusing the same function and passing an extra value. Is this the right way to do it? How do other experienced people solve this problem.

Comment: My answer in 2020: use Vue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your parent component to maintain the state with the value of each input field present in 'Input' child components, then you can achieve this with a single change handler in the following way:

```
  handleChange(id, value) {
    this.setState({
      [id]: value
    });
  }
```

where the `id` and `value` are obtained from the `Input` component.

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/rrJXjK and the full code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input1: null,
      input2: null
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id, value) {
    this.setState({
      [id]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>     
        <Input id="input1" 
               changeHandler={this.handleChange} />       
        <Input id="input2" 
               changeHandler={this.handleChange} />        
        <p>See input1 in parent: {this.state.input1}</p>
        <p>See input2 in parent: {this.state.input2}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userInput: null
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const enteredText = event.target.valuel
    this.setState({
      userInput: enteredText
    }, this.props.changeHandler(this.props.id, enteredText));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" 
             placeholder="input1 here..." 
             value={this.state.userInput}
             onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Ankit, would you like me to anything to the answer or does it give you the solution?

Comment: That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `event delegation`, just like the traditional ways.

That is, just bind a function to the parent `form` element, and listens to all the events bubbling up from the children `input` elments.